# Post Feed in Yammer through c#

Tags: c#, yammer

I am very new to yammer.

I need to develop a c# application which posts feed in yammer, simply say "Hello World".

I saw several blogs and forumns.

I would be happy if anyone post small sample or some refferences where it is explained in a structured way.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5):

You can check this github project : [Yammer.SimpleApi](https://github.com/RaynaldM/Yammer.SimpleAPI)
or you can use directly this [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Yammer.SimpleAPI/)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that it's your own project. Self promotion like the one you made are welcome though since they're right on topic! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The code at [here](https://github.com/kdavie/yammer.net) would be useful.Some API endpoints like Post,Like, Follow are working good in that project. Replace the older version of API with newer one referring the [API documentation](http://developer.yammer.com/restapi/) provided by Yammer. Have you read the docs at https://developer.yammer.com/introduction/ and https://developer.yammer.com/authentication/? There is also a [quickstart](https://developer.yammer.com/oauth2-quickstart/).

Join Yammer development network to get some guidance.

Comment: Where is the Yammer development network!? I need some help on another project and my question here hasn't got any attention!

Answer (score 0):

For a newbie to develop an app, [this](http://sunnybahree.blogspot.com/2012/05/yammer-api-call-from-dot-net-c.html?showComment=1380264363886#c7902016442486500336) could be useful.